# Ubuntu 16.04 DisplayPort monitor not recognized

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

Running Ubuntu 16.04 in a Hyper-V VM on a Windows 8.1 workstation. Ubuntu Display Settings only recognizes the "Built-In" display, not the higher-resolution second monitor connected via DisplayPort. Others with this issue updated their Nvidia graphics driver. Mine is the Intel HD 5000 driver for which the system detects no driver update. How can I get Ubuntu to recognize the second monitor so that I can improve resolution of the displayed desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/702628/ubuntu-hyper-v-guest-display-resolution-win-10-15-04).

(Don't forget to "sudo update-grub" before rebooting.)