# Running Ubuntu in the new Windows 10 using WSL Windows System for Linux (not hyper-V)

Tags: virtualbox, display, display-resolution, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hyper-v

This post answered a number of my questions.

[Ubuntu Hyper-V Guest Display Resolution Win 10 + 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/702628/ubuntu-hyper-v-guest-display-resolution-win-10-15-04)

1. It appears that Windows 10 virtual machine Hyper-V will run Ubuntu.
2. There are graphics drivers included.
3. There is a way to solve display resolution problems on high res screens.
4. It will work on a SurfacePro 3
5. Ubuntu 15.04 works as a guest OS

That leaves just several other questions.

What version should I install to run OpenCPN (linux version) for the next 1-2 years?

I think I would like a graphic interface like Gnome, I did use Unity for a while.

How much disk space is generally required?

I have 190gb free but would like to keep the use down.

PS: I just installed the MS App Ubuntu 18.0LTS into the Windows 10 virtual space and it appears to just be a "Terminal" version with Bash and some other utilities, which does not have GTK. I tried to run OpenCPN which is graphics intensive and uses openGL and it fails.  See the [Opencpn thread here](http://www.cruisersforum.com/forums/showthread.php?p=2895024#post2895024)

PSS: I just realized that I was using WSL  "Windows Subsystem for Linux", not Hyper-V!   [Windows Subsystem for Linux Installation Guide for Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) which is an easy switch in the Windows settings. It looks to me like this will support any installation of linux. I don't know about use of clipboard between guest and host yet.

PSS: Can anyone confirm that they have been using Ubuntu in Windows10 "WSL"?

Additional Information
Custom Linux Installs and "Sideloading"
[Creating a Custom Linux Distro for WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/build-custom-distro)

[Roll your own and submit to MS for approval](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL-DistroLauncher)

It appears that this June there will be a new Windows Store app for Ubuntu 19.04 using WSL2

See ["When can I try this?" at the bottom](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/05/...system-linux-2)

However I believe this Store app is just for the "Terminal" version and not the full version.  I will need the fully operable version of 18.04 or 19.04 with Gnome and Gtk etc. to run OpenCPN (graphics intensive opengl)

Comment: you tagged virtualbox as well, this means you know about it/are willing to use it instead of Hyper-V? I personally would recomend sticking with ubuntu, but take the latest : 19.04. 18.04 is LTS but unfortunatelly even though it's a legitimate heir to the LTS throne, it's a bit of a Joffrey.

Comment: Thank you Tatsu. Yes, Vbox is fine and I can go back to it if necessary. Thought I would try Hyper-V, however  I suspect it does not have the advantage of interoperable clipboard paste and copy with the host system and guest, a question I should get answered.   I will use 19.04 as you suggest! Thank you.

Comment: it doeas actually. virtualbox happens to be the first to have supported it. if you're satisfied with my answer, you can mark it with the checkbox.

Comment: I'm new to this forum and will check you answer. I guess I should ask subsequent questions separately! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend ubuntu 19.04 then ubuntu 20.04 LTS when it comes out next year

and VirtualBox for the VM software.

Comment: Just had an answer from a friend. See this post.  http://www.cruisersforum.com/forums/f134/o5-linux-in-ubuntu-18-04lts-for-windows10-218568.html#post2895598  Apparently it will work.

Comment: http://www.cruisersforum.com/forums/f134/o5-linux-in-ubuntu-18-04lts-for-windows10-218568.html#post2895598

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on WSL.  I still use WSL 1 because WSL 2 still is very buggy, and communication with the XServer and pulseaudio is broken if I use WSL 2.  I run both BASH sessions and a number of GUI apps.

Some GUI apps do not work, like the gnome-software app.  Some do, like Synaptic, gnome-commander, and quite a few others others.  It takes experimentation and some additional software to run them.

I also am using VcXsrv X Server 1.20.1.4 for Windows and pulseaudio 1.1 for Win32 so that I can get sound with firefox.  I have cupsd service set up to autorun when I logon to Windows (so I can print from firefox and so forth), along with the XServer and pulseaudio.

This has allowed me to use various Linux apps side by side with Windows apps without using a full virtual machine.  And I run them using shortcuts in I put in the Windows 10 Start Screen.  But, if you want to run gnome and such, you will need to use Hyper-V unless you use VirtualBox.  They don't play nice together so you will need to disable Hyper-V if you plan to use VirtualBox.